# Telerik reportexcel export exceed more than one page

Tags: excel, telerik, export, report

I have a telerik report. After the report is generated, user can be exported to PDF, word, rtf, etc. Except Excel format, every export formats one page per page. I mean if report has one page, the export will generate one page. However, in Excel, it changes to 2 pages. For some reasons, Telerk report engines expands the width of certain cells. Then it renders a single page to 2 page. I guess Telerik believes users will care less about the number of pages it exports in Excel format. Our client does care about it.

I was going to shrink the spaces, so the report will be big enough to fit in one page in Excel. That is going to be a problem because that may cause some cosmetic problem on PDF or other format.

Any property I can set to make sure Excel export.

I am developing this report using C# under visual studio 2013.

Thanks